# Run shell script as another user after git hook

Tags: git, hook

I'm trying to execute a shell script that initialize the deployment of a web application after a git push. The shell script must be run as root ( or another user that is not the git user ).

Searching in SO I've found a way to launch a shell script as another user and is working for me when I launch it directly from the terminal:

```
sudo -u root sh /home/path/to/run.sh
```

The problem is that when I push to the server, the hook is launching ( I'm making sure that the post-receive program is running ), but the `run.sh` program is not getting executed, and I don't any way to debug it...

Any clues?, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
# su -m user -c '/path/some_command -with -options /some/other/file'
```